# How can I mark additional virtual desktops to differentiate them easily?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-desktop

It is really awesome that I can use multiple virtual desktops with Windows. However, I often confuse the different desktops with each other and open programs multiple times on both desktops and so on. I just can't tell the difference.

The easiest way for me would be to set a different background (permanently), but this doesn't seem to be possible (for whatever reason).

Is there a good way to clearly mark additional virtual desktops as such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Windows 10 newest within the last year, you can rename the desktops.

You cannot use different background colors because each desktop is just a view of the main desktop.

Open Task View so you can see the collection of desktops, right click on the Desktop icon along the top, and select Rename. Rename it to what you wish.

I have two ongoing Desktops:  Regular and Base.  Easy to differentiate when I click on Task View.

Desktops are much the same. You can try an app that allows multiple instances. That will sit in the system tray and may provide the visual clue you need.

So for example, VMware Workstation is running in my main desktop and so is in the system tray. My Base Desktop is not running VMware so I can see in the System Tray which desktop I am in. I can verify with Task View.

Comment: That's OK. But I'm looking for a visual clue without having to open up something like Task View

Comment: Desktops are all pretty much the same. You would need an app that has multiple instances and then set up an instance for each desktop that provides that visual clue for you. Such app can sit in the system tray.. I made a small amendment in my answer to provide for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are some programs you open in both desktops, they will number the instances in the taskbar. Total commander is perfect for me, i use it all the time anyway.

[image: taskbar]

It is just a brief difference, but easy to learn it.
Additionally, you can just hit the desktop switch shortcuts (Win+Cntr+ArrowKey)

Comment: It should be possible with Windows 11, so I just have to buy a new PC and update Windows... 